# How to resolve problem with cannot access offset of type string to string?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code, and it gives me the error **Cannot access offset of type string on string**. I can't find a solution to this problem because I don't know where the error is, but I suspect it is in the second argument of the where() function. I would be grateful if someone could help me solve this problem.

```
  $user = $this->User::findOrFail($id);
        $lastName = $model->lastName;
        $result = (array)$lastName;

        $variable = Class::where($result, fn($item) => $item['value'] === true);
```

Comment: `$this->User::findOrFail($id)`? Did you mean `User::findOrFail($id)`?

Comment: the error should be giving you a line number and also a stack trace where you could work back to this code ... what is `$item` supposed to be in that anonymous function?

Comment: you should have the line where the code hits